# Using FlatList to display Tabs in React-Native Nativebase Tabs

Tags: react-native, tabs, react-native-flatlist, native-base

i am trying to iterate through a data source and display `Tabs` based on that data source and i am using `FlatList` for that here is the code

```
<Tabs
   renderTabBar={() => <ScrollableTab />}
   tabBarUnderlineStyle={{backgroundColor: "#4285f4"}}
   tabBarBackgroundColor="#fff"
>
    <FlatList
        data={this.state.dataSource}
        renderItem={({item}) =>
            <Tab
               heading={item.title}
            >
                <Text>Tab details</Text>
            </Tab>
    />
</Tabs>
```

this always gives me an error saying

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'child.props.heading.props') the error is located at ScrollableTabView
```

i dont know whats wrong i tried using `map` instead of `FlatList` and it worked fine

Comment: You can not use FlatList as child component of the Tabs, child component must be Tab component. Why do you need the Flatlist, for vertical tabs?

Comment: Ok they are not vertical i forgot to put the horizontal prop...at first i did it with a map and the tab just started flickering like crazy on ios...i thought maybe using flatlist would fix it

Comment: How many tabs you have?

Comment: Its based on the data but maximum 8

Comment: Did you test with publish version or dev?

Comment: No...do u think that could be the problem?

Comment: Do you use react-native-scrollable-tab-view


?

Comment: No i am importing ScrollableTab from Native base

Comment: i added the answer

Comment: Ok thanks i will try it and let you know:)

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace Nativebase tab component with

https://github.com/ptomasroos/react-native-scrollable-tab-view/blob/master/README.md.

And  is no need  to use a Flatlist component as a child component  for the  better performance, it will not work.